# Laravel 5.2 compare dates that are strings?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, laravel-5

I have a table that contains two dates: start_date and end_date. Both of these columns are string. When I try to query to get the records comparing against these dates, Laravel treats them as strings, instead of dates.

For example, for this query:

```
Schedule::whereDate('start_date','<=',date('m/d/Y'))->whereDate('end_date','>=',date('m/d/Y'))->get();
```

No results are returned, which is not correct.

Any thoughts? Or any other way to compare dates that are strings?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are the columns string? You'd have to do a string compare which probably isn't going to be useful. You're going to have to do some nasty trickery either in mysql or laravel to make this work. I'll see if I can figure out an example but the real solution is to convert from strings to dates.

Comment: not sure why they weren't created as datetimes, but that's what I have at the moment. I was hoping there could be options to query strings as dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make these columns [datetime](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns) instead of string:

```
$table->dateTime('start_date');
$table->dateTime('end_date');
```

Also, it's a good idea to add these columns to the [$dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'start_date', 'end_date'];
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to understand the impact of changing these fields to dateTime given that there's already some logic built to compare the existing strings (which most probably is wrong)

Comment: Changing the columns to datetime did the trick, just had to change a few queries here and there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Carbon. Gonna work great for time-stuff

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/